# Create new thread in a loop with new parameters

Tags: java, android

I want to create new `Runnable` in a loop. However, it is not possible to use a variable within an inner class. I cannot use global/instance variable because it generates wrong results. My program is similar to the simplified code that follows:

```
public class RunManager {
    public void runManager(int delay, final Context context) {
        for (int dim = 7; dim < 227; dim++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RandomKernels randomKernels = new RandomKernels();
                    try {
                        randomKernels.foo(context, dim);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread cnnThread = new Thread(r);
            cnnThread.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error is: `Variable 'dim' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final.`

Comment: do you really want to create 220 different threads?

Comment: @BMacedo Thanks for your fast response. Yes, each threads finishes its computation after 5 ms. I am trying to perform a simulated workload to monitor the hardware characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to access a non final variable from a new thread. In order for variable to ne accesed from new thread it needs to be declared as final. In your cas you can just copy the dim int to a final int array of size 1 then access the array from thread.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most legible way of doing it would be to create a constructor for your `Runnable` which accepts an int as parameter. Such as:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

   public MyRunnable(Context context, int dim) {
       // save parameters as class variables
   }

   public void run() {
       // do the work
   }
}
```

Then call it:

```
Runnable r = new MyRunnable(context, dim);
new Thread(r).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `final int[] dim` if you want to have access to the value within inner class.

```
public class RunManager {

    public void runManager(int delay, final Context context) {
        for (final int dim[] = {7}; dim[1] < 227; dim[1]++) {
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RandomKernels randomKernels = new RandomKernels();
                    try {
                        randomKernels.foo(context, dim[1]);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread cnnThread = new Thread(r);
            cnnThread.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2 - use field:

```
public class RunManager {

    private int _dim;

    public void runManager(int delay, final Context context) {
        for (int dim = 7; dim < 227; dim++) {
            _dim = dim;
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RandomKernels randomKernels = new RandomKernels();
                    try {
                        randomKernels.foo(context, _dim);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };
            Thread cnnThread = new Thread(r);
            cnnThread.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Option 3 - iterate in another method and add `final int dim` as method argument:

```
private void createThreads(int delay, final Object context) {
    for (int dim = 7; dim < 227; dim++) {
        runManager(delay, context, dim);
    }
}

public void runManager(int delay, final Context context, final int dim) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            RandomKernels randomKernels = new RandomKernels();
            try {
                randomKernels.foo(context, dim);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    Thread cnnThread = new Thread(r);
    cnnThread.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Option 4 - use custom runnable. You can implement class as recommended by @BMacedo or create abstract class and implement logic in inner class.

```
public class RunManager {

    public void runManager(int delay, final Context context) {
        for (int dim = 7; dim < 227; dim++) {
            CustomRunnable r = new CustomRunnable() {
                private int _dim;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RandomKernels randomKernels = new RandomKernels();
                    try {
                        randomKernels.foo(context, _dim);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(tag, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                public void setDim(int dim) {
                    _dim = dim;
                }
            };

            r.setDim(dim);

            Thread cnnThread = new Thread(r);
            cnnThread.start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    abstract class CustomRunnable implements Runnable {
        public abstract void setDim(int dim);
    }
}
```